# Get Distinct Values With Consistent Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with some IDs and a flag of whether or not the person should be deleted. There are 2 sets of IDs in the table, 1 primary ID, and then a secondary ID as well. A single primary ID can be in the table multiple times if it has multiple secondary IDs.

Take this set of data for example:

```
primary_id       secondary_id      delete_flag
   1                 ajdkl              1
   1                 jnami              0
   2                 janda              0
   3                 wwqia              1
   4                 lamse              1
   4                 pppqw              1
   4                 aneqw              0
   5                 gaabs              1
   5                 iikam              1
```

in that example I would be looking to have 3 and 5 returned since they are the only 2 where all instances of their primary ID have a deleted_flag = 1.

What I am running in to in this query:

```
select primary_id from table where delete_flag = 1 group by primary_id
```

is that it is returning all instances where there at least a single 1 present, I want only the ones where every instance has a 1 present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses, where the primary_ids whose total number of records is equal to the total number of deleted flag records should be selected.

```
select primary_id 
from mytable 
group by primary_id 
having count(delete_flag) = count(case when delete_flag = 1 then 1 end)
```

Another option is to use `MIN()` and `MAX()`, where the deleted_flag's min and max should both equal 1.

```
select primary_id 
from mytable 
group by primary_id 
having min(delete_flag) = 1 and max(delete_flag) = 1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bit6k7K_)

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to direct how to get the primary_id's where there is a mix of 1s and 0's as well?

Comment: You can use `having min(delete_flag) = 0 and max(delete_flag) = 1`

Comment: `having count(*) = ` would be more obvious. Count only counts non-nulls, if everything is non-null then it's the same as `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Thanks for remark @Charlieface,  `count(*)` can be used in place of `count(delete_flag)`, if `delete_flag` allow null values and those null records need to be counted.

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from myTable t1 where not exists 
(select * from myTable t2 
 where t1.primary_id=t2.primary_id and t2.Delete_flag = 0);
```

EDIT: If you meant to get just primary_id distinct values:

```
select distinct primary_id from myTable t1 where not exists 
(select * from myTable t2 
 where t1.primary_id=t2.primary_id and t2.Delete_flag = 0);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/4mMuvsU2)